# Apply inbox label to mail in gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

If I'm reading an email and I accidentally hit archive, how can I undo this?

It used to be simple: I could use the back button and there was a "move to inbox" menu item. Failing that, I believe one could drag the inbox label to the open message. Now, the only way I see available is to search for the message so that it appears in a list, and then drag that message to the inbox label. Is there any option for un-archiving while actively displaying the message? This comes up fairly often.

Answer (score 5):

When you click "Archive" you get a little yellow bar at the top of the window asking you if you want to undo your action. Click Undo to restore the mail to your inbox.
[image: Undo archiving]
If you continued browsing around it disappears.

If you really want the "Move to inbox" button you'll have to search for the mail, or find it in the `All mail` folder.

[image: All mail]

You can still use the back-button to get to the mail but it seams that for some reason you can no longer move it to the inbox from there. A workaround is to move it to another label (preferably one at the top of your label list), go to that label and then to the mail. Now you can move it to the inbox (in the "Move to" menu). This is only useful if you don't remember the name if the mail (or something else to search for), and if some time has passed so that it won't appear at the top if the `All mail` folder.